# SP2013: How to hide the links of custom view?

Tags: view

In the site collection, we have "Pages" library. We created two custom view viewA and viewB for it. On one of page we add the "Pages" as web part. The links viewA and viewB are listed at the top of page.

How can we disable the links?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Edit that page
2. Edit web part Pages
3. Under Miscellaneous **check** *Disable view selector menu*
4. Click OK and Save page.

   :)

Comment: Just for the sake of reference, this option does not exist in Sharepoint Online. Since the question specifically asks for the 2013 version, the solution is perfectly valid.

Comment: Exists in 2019. Thank You @Mark-l!)

Comment: @BiLaL It exists in Sharepoint Online, at least as of today