# SharePoint Online - How to hide all items view from certain users

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, hide-elements

I have a SharePoint list where users add their requests. 
How to hide **AllItems** view from the users?.
I still want **AllItems** view to be available for admins.
I want to just give access to MyItems view, which will be the only view available for users.
How to achieve this?

**Note** - I tried to restrict users by creating a custom permission level, but that didn't help me in hiding **AllItems** view.

I also found this [how to hide the views from document library or list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146411/how-to-hide-the-views-from-document-library-or-list) , But looking for a better solution to hide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to restrict the views to certain users, for your requirement you need to set the item-level permissions. Go to list settings >> Advanced Settings >> Under Read access (check: Read items that were created by the user). This allows the user to read/view their items created by them. Admin should be able to view all items.

[image]

Comment: Only thing: if admins need to modify the items and you change the "Create and Edit access" to "Create items and edit items that were created by the user", they would no longer be able to edit anything they did not create. This would override their access. I believe I've had issues with this before.

Answer (score -1):

You can use audience targeting for that, and set admin group there.

Comment: Can you please add some more detailed steps for this? So the answer will be helpful

Comment: Add list view webpart on the page with all items view. edit that and in audience targeting set admin group.. So in this case admin can see all item. And for the above mentioned list view (MyItem View) set properties that " create and edit item that have created by users.